# What ports should I allow for a MySQL server?

Tags: firewall

What ports are required by Ubuntu to run properly? I want to deny all non-essential ports on the system. At the moment, I have ports 22, 443, 53, and 3306 open. Are there any other ports I should allow/deny?

Answer (score 1):

> What ports are required by Ubuntu to run properly?

Even if you will close all your tcp/udp ports, ubuntu will technically still run properly.

> I want to deny all non-essential ports on the system.

Here essential is relative term and you should state the functionalities you require.

> At the moment, I have ports 22, 443, 53, and 3306 open. Are there any other ports I should allow/deny?

So you have opened ports for ssh, https, DNS, mysql. If you do not require any other service then you can close the port ( specifically kill the program using the ports ). Just check the open ports using

`sudo netstat -tulpn`

> You can learn about netstat and the flags -t -u -l -p -n by visiting the man page of the netstat command

It will also give you the pid of the program name.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the `netstat` command. The functionality I want is just to be able to use the update and upgrade commands to receive package updates. What ports do I need to open for that?

Comment: Then I do not think you even need to open any port, when you will run the command, the process will automatically open some ports, do the process and close them.